# how to use different sender than credentials use in smtp configuration in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi in my web application we are sending mail to the person who`s birthday is in current week, so while sending mail i don`t want sender as email id which is used in smtp configuration i want to use different email id as sender,

Can any one tell me how i can achieve this,

Answer (score 0):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Sends mail with authentification
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="recipients"></param>
    /// <param name="from"></param>
    /// <param name="subject"></param>
    /// <param name="body"></param>
    /// <param name="isHTMLbody"></param>
    /// <param name="SMTPhost"></param>
    /// <param name="priority"></param>
    /// <param name="credentials"></param>
    /// <param name="port"></param>
    /// <param name="enableSsl"></param>
    public static void SendMailWithAuthentication(List<string> recipients, string from, string subject, string body, bool isHTMLbody,
        string SMTPhost, System.Net.Mail.MailPriority priority, System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials, int? port, bool enableSsl)
    {
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        foreach (string recipient in recipients)
        {
            message.To.Add(recipient);
        }
        message.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(from);
        message.IsBodyHtml = isHTMLbody;
        message.Body = body;
        message.Priority = priority;
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        client.Credentials = credentials;
        client.Host = SMTPhost;
        if (port != null)
        {
            client.Port = (int)port;
        }
        client.EnableSsl = enableSsl;
        client.Send(message);
        message.Dispose();
    }
```

For "from" parameter you can use what ever email as you want as while it's valid email address. Just a sample it could be "bill.gates2@microsoft.com" and it will work.

If this is not working you should contact your email provider, because they are preventing you from doing this.

Comment: I don`t want to show email id given in credentials as from id when it comes to inbox, for eg. if abc@gmail.com is used in credentials and in from there is xyz@gmail.com i want to show xyz@gmail.com as sender when mail comes in inbox

Comment: Use my code and you will see that sender is displayed as you have entered in "from" parameter. This parameter can be totaly different from passed credentials (user that acutualy sends an email).

Comment: So you will call this method like this:
SendMailWithAuthentication(new List<>{"reciever@email.com"}, "xyz@gmail.com", "My subject", "My body", false, "some.smtp.net", 0, new System.Net.NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com", "password"));

Comment: This will show reciever like email was send from xyz@gmail.com not abc@gmail.com